# change the order of fields in the forms of external lists

Tags: jquery, external-list

I have an external list and forms contain fields which are ordered alphabetically. I would like to customize the order of fields in all the forms. I thought of using jquery, but that is giving me some issues as it does not work straight forward in SharePoint. I had a look in SharePoint Designer, but it does not give me the possibility to reorder the fields.

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to reorder the fields in a more customizable way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the default order of the fields are determined by the order of the corresponding TypeDescriptor elements in the BDC model (for the list view see the finder method, for the new / edit / display form views see the specific finder method). For the list view, you can change the order as you would do in the case of a standard SharePoint list / view.